# Changing AWS VPC Built in local route table & network interface with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I've created my own VPC with Terraform, however some parameters where the resource is created, could not be edited, like

1. I can not find the attribute, which is responsible for route table which is unnamed and uses for local connection (10.0.0.0/16 Local)(Main route table)
2. Also, when I'm creating a EIP it uses ENI (Interface), however it also not in my control

Maybe someone already did the similar, I would be appreciated for any help

P.S. Terraform already created vpc, subnets, route tables, igw, nat .....

Comment: I know, that I can manage the "aws_main_route_table_association", but it does not gives me an option to add a tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not find the attribute, which is responsible for route table which is unnamed and uses for local connection (10.0.0.0/16 Local)(Main route table)

You **can't edit nor delete** `10.0.0.0/16 Local`. Its always present in your route tables, thus there is no attribute to change it.

> Also, when I'm creating a EIP it uses ENI (Interface), however it also not in my control

Not sure what do you mean by this. EIP doesn't have ENI by itself. EIP must be attached to an ENI to work. If you attach it to, let's say, NAT gateway, the **ENI used is AWS managed**, not yours. So you have no control over it.

On the other hand, if you attach EIP to your own ENI for your EC2 instance, you have options to manage the ENI.

Comment: 1. So it means I can not even add a single tag to that Route Table (10.0.0.0/16)?
-
2. Yes I'm ataching them into my NAT Gateway, does it mean to control the EIP I have to create an ENI and atach them to my NAT Gateway?

Comment: @Unity Hi. Off course, you can add new routes to the main route table. But you can't change the local route `10.0.0.0/16` in that table. The local route is always present. NAT Gateway is fully AWS managed service. You have no control over it in the way you would have if it was a NAT instance. So you can't add ENI to it.